# org-mode: how to print agenda showing only some categories

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, print

I'm trying to print today's agenda hiding some categories.

I'm using C-u < to hide the categories I don't want, but when I print (either the buffer or by selecting the text and using `lpr-region`), it prints also the categories I've hidden.

How can I print only what I see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this [webpage](https://orgmode.org/manual/Exporting-agenda-views.html) and tried the C-x C-w combo using a pdf file extension?